# Convert object to byte array and vice-versa in python

Tags: python, networking, serialization, message

I use Python and send and receive packets to/from external c++ server (so pickle can't help) and need to serialize and deserialize python objects to/from byte arrays.

Serialize is easy:

```
class MsgBase(Structure):
    def __init__(self, my_type):
        self.m_type = my_type

    def get_buffer(self):
        return bytearray(self)

    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('m_type', c_uint8)]

message = MsgBase(1)
arr = message.get_buffer()
```

But how to deserialize this buffer back?

need something like this:

```
message = MsgBase(0)
message.deserialize_from_bytearray(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution:

message = MsgBase.from_buffer(arr)